# Sitecore Web Api default context language

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore, sitecore8

My target is if the request is

```
http://myapi.com/da-DK/api/products/all
```

I would return the products from the DK language.

But if the request is

```
http://myapi.com/api/products/all
```

meaning no language is requested, it would return products from a default language. In this case "en".

This is what I have in the webapiconfig.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "mypi",
                  routeTemplate: "{language}/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, language = "en" }
              );
```

The problem is if no language requested, it does not take english an default. Rather it takes the last requested language.
Can I somehow force sitecore to use default language if no language is requested?

Comment: Can you please post your code sample for the controller action?

Comment: Is a cookie with a language value passed with the request to http://myapi.com/api/products/all ?

Comment: @Jeroen no. I am not passing anything explicitely.

Comment: I have solved the problem with a "custom language resolver" implementing "HTTPRequestProcessor". 
It checks if there is any language in the request other wise sets the context language to "en" and the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I know you solved this using a resolver but I think those are 2 different routes..meaning you can create another route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "mypinolang",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, language = "en" }
          );
```

Then, you can have your API method to accept "language" as a parameter.  However, this answer may not work depending on your other API methods as it can get confusing.